# How do I get statistics on which hashtags a Twitter account has used?

Tags: social-media, twitter

I'm trying to review how a client has used Twitter so that they get an understanding which hashtags staff have used over the years.

Update: I'm interested in seeing which tags were most used and which got most engagement. Many staff have had access to the account over the years and most have just used the web interface.

Comment: Most tools allow to track a specific hashtag, or track the overall statistics of a specific account. As far as I understand you want to know which hashtags from a specific account where the most used or the most successful in terms of engagements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://analytics.twitter.com CSV-Export or the api to get a list of all tweets.

Then you could do some Excel magic to
1. extract all hashtags in each tweet
2. find most used hashtags
3. …